# Server 2019 - Print server failed to share printer after increasing CPU/RAM for VM

Tags: windows-server-2019, print-server

I have a new Win2019 server VM with the print server running. This replaced an older 2012 version. Over the weekend I shut it down, increased CPU/RAM and started it. As of this morning, no printers work. Error log has Error #315: failed to share printer for all 279 printers. No other changes were made. The print server is part of a domain.

Anyone have this kind of behavior happen?

Comment: We need more detail, did you restarted another time ? does the domain controller is reachable by the server, does the ip configuration is configured correctly (pointing correct DC), etc..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the previous print server was restarted with the same IP address. I opted for the neuclear option of deleting the server from AD, reverting the printer server to Workgroup, then re-adding it to the domain. This got rid of all the printers in AD and when the *correct* print server came back online it published all the printers.

I believe there is a way to force the DC to re-publish the printer list, but I've not found it yet (the default domain policy for printer pruning had default values). I believe it would have saved time over dropping the server from AD and re-adding it. However, there may have been other dependencies and perhaps caching that would preclude leaving it in AD.

Perhaps deleting all the published printers, then restarting the print spooler service on the print server would have fixed the problem, but we needed to act fast to fix the printing issues.